# Printing sorted numbers from k different trees without knowing which is which

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree

Given `k` binary search trees `T_1 ,..., T_k`, with total of `n` different numbers.

For each `1 <= i <= k-2` : `T_i < T_{i+2}` (all `T_i` numbers are less than `T_{i+2}` numbers).

How to print the `n` numbers sorted?

Time: `O(n + k*log(k))`

You don't know the indices of the trees, meaning that `Sort(k Trees)` does not necessarily gets the first tree as `T_1` and so on...

Comment: Do you mean that input trees already have `T_i < T_{i+2}` property or they needed to be sorted to satisfy this property?

Comment: @valdem they have this property. We need to print the `n` numbers sorted

Answer (score 0):

This task can be solved in `O(n)` complexity if trees already sorted, i.e. satisfy property

> For each `1 <= i <= k-2` : `T_i < T_{i+2}` **[1]**

At first for simplicity in this task we can use array of sorted arrays instead of array of binary search trees. Complexity of output all elements in sorted array and BST have same complexity `O(t)` where `t` count of elements in this array/tree. And in this solution we don't need find operation on BST or operations with balancing.

What if instead of property **[1]** we have property "For each `1 <= i <= k-1` : `T_i < T_{i+1}`" ? We can output all elements in first array then output elements in second array and so on. Complexity will be O(n).

Difference between this two properties in that for original property when we output elements in `i`-th array we need to take into account next `i+1`-th array and output some elements in `i+1`-th array too. I.e. we output elements in `i`-th and `i+1`-th arrays at `i`-th iteration. We finish output elements in `i`-th and `i+1`-th arrays only when there are no elements in `i`-th array, but can be (should be) elements in `i+1`-th array. So we need to save position in `i+1`-th array (let it be x) and on iteration `i+1` start not from beginning of `i+1`-th array but from position `x` (and start on array `i+2`-th from first position).

Solution for BST absolutely similar to arrays.

Comment: As I mentioned, we don't know the indices of the trees, meaning that `Sort(k Trees)` does not necessarily gets the first tree as T_1 and so on... If we knew the indices, then your solution is the correct one, but we don't.